# Solving transcendental equation with secant method

Tags: algorithm, precision, evaluation, equation-solving, transcendental-equation

Good time of day.

There is a function `Phi(alpha) = sinc(pi*a/l*sin(alpha)) = sin(pi*a/l*sin(alpha))/(pi*a/l*sin(alpha))`, domain is `[-pi/2;pi/2]`.

I need to solve equation `Phi(alpha) = c` using the secant method. Default `c` is `0.7`. As `Phi` is even function, we mostly work with non-negative space and search positive root.

Method requires the sin() realization and the choise of two start points. Also we need arcsin() and sqrt() and some other auxiliary functions. **Phi(), sin(), arcsin() and sqrt() work properly and precisely** (were tested separately). Secant method iterations are limited by Garwick's method – checking stop condition | alpha_n+1 - alpha_n | > | alpha_n - alpha_n-1 |. It could be modified, considering equality (stopping immediately if ">" and stopping after 10 consecutive "=="). But this modification doesn't give big advabtages (and **doesn't affect the problem described below**).

The problem is, solving function (`Solve_Sinc`) give good result (errors of order `10^(-7)` — `10^(-9)`) for one test examples, and very bad for others. **Start points choise doesn't seem to affect it**. The program output be like "error : solving result", bad examples are marked with comments in code.

So, the code is:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

const float Pi = 3.1415927;
float abs(float);
float fact(int);
float pot_sgn(int);
float potent(float,int);
float rad_to_deg(float);

float sqrt(float);
float arcsin(float, int iter = 6);
float sin(float, int iter = 4);

float Phi(float, float);
float Solve_Sinc(float, float, float c = 0.7);

int main(void){
        
    float a_size = 0.1;
    
    cout << "__________" << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.001, 0.35) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.00713124
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.01, 0.35) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.0713724
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.015, 0.35) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.107173
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.04, 0.35) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.289264
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.05, 0.35) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.364582
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.06, 0.35) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.08, 0.35) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.1, 0.35) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be ???
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.11, 0.35) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be ???
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.3, 0.35) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.5, 0.35) << endl;
    cout << "__________" << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.001) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.01) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.015) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.04) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.180529
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.05) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.226366
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.06) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.08) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.1) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.11) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.3) << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.5) << endl;
    cout << "__________" << endl;
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.001, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.000780871
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.01, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.00780879
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.015, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.0117133
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.04, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.0312399
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.05, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.0390535
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.06, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.0468694
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.08, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.0625104
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.1, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.0781667
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.11, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.0860018
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.3, 0.99) << endl;  //Incorrect: must be 0.236459
    cout << Solve_Sinc(a_size, 0.5, 0.99) << endl;
    cout << "__________" << endl;
        
    getch();
    return 0;
}

float Solve_Sinc(float a, float l, float c){
    if(a <= 0.0 || l <= 0.0 || c < 0.0){
        cout << "Piston size and wavelength must be positive;\ncriterion must be non-negative!" << endl;
        return 0.0;
    }
    
    float alph_old, alph_0, alph_1, k;
    k = a/l*Pi;
    alph_old = 0.0;
    alph_0 = 0.0;
    
    if(l/a > 1.0){
        if(Phi(k,Pi/2.0) - c > 0.0){return Pi/2.0;}
        alph_1 = Pi/2.0 ;
    } else if(l/a > 0.5){
        alph_1 = arcsin(l/a);
    } else {
        alph_1 = arcsin(2.0*l/a);
    }
    
    bool rep = true;
    int eq = 0;
    while(rep){  //Modified Garwick's method
        alph_old = alph_0;
        alph_0 = alph_1;
        alph_1 = alph_0 - (Phi(k,alph_0) - c) * (alph_0 - alph_old) / (Phi(k,alph_0) - Phi(k,alph_old));
        if(abs(alph_1 - alph_0) > abs(alph_0 - alph_old)){rep = false;}
        else if(abs(alph_0 - alph_old) - abs(alph_1 - alph_0) <= 1e-6){eq += 1;}
        else{eq = 0;}
        if(eq == 10){rep = false;}
    }
    
    /*
    do{
        alph_old = alph_0;
        alph_0 = alph_1;
        alph_1 = alph_0 - (Phi(k,alph_0) - c) * (alph_0 - alph_old) / (Phi(k,alph_0) - Phi(k,alph_old));
    }
    while(abs(alph_1 - alph_0) < abs(alph_0 - alph_old));  //Common Garwick's method
    */
    
    cout << Phi(k, alph_0) - c << " : ";
    return alph_0;
}

float Phi(float k, float x){
    if(abs(x) <= 1e-6){return 1.0;}
    return sin(k*sin(x))/(k*sin(x));
}

float sin(float x, int iter){
    if(x < 0.0){return -sin(-x);}
    
    while (x >= 2.0*Pi){
        x -= 2.0*Pi;
    }
    
    if(x > Pi){return -sin(2.0*Pi - x);}
    
    if(x > Pi/2.0){return sin(Pi-x);}
    
    float z = 0.0;
    for(int i=iter;i>=0;i--){
        z += pot_sgn(i)*(potent(x,2*i+1)/fact(2*i+1));
    }
    return z;
}

float arcsin(float x, int iter){
    if(x < 0.0){return -arcsin(-x);}
    
    if(x - (float)1.0 >= 1e-6){
        cout << x << ":" << endl;
        cout << "Absolute value of arcsin() argument can't be more than 1!" << endl;
        return 0.0;
    }
    
    if(x >= 0.7071068){return Pi/2.0 - arcsin(sqrt(1.0 - x*x));}
    
    if(x > 0.5 && x < 0.7071068){iter *= 2;}
    float z = 0.0;
    for(int i=iter;i>=0;i--){
        z += (potent(x,2*i+1)*fact(2*i))/(fact(i)*fact(i)*potent(4.0,i)*(2*i+1));
    }
    return z;
}

float sqrt(float x){
    float prec = 1e-6;
    if(abs(x) < prec*10.0){return 0.0;}
    if(x < 0.0){
        cout << "Argument for sqrt() must be non-negative!" << endl;
        return 0.0;
    }
    float y = x;
    float delta;
    float cnt = x;
    if(x >= 1.0){
        do{
            cnt *= 0.1;
            prec *= 10.0;
        }
        while(cnt >= 1.0);
    }
    
    do{
        y = (y + x/y) / 2.0;
        delta = x - y*y;}
    while(delta < -prec || delta > prec);
    
    return y;
}

float rad_to_deg(float x){
    return (x/Pi)*180.0;
}

float potent(float x,int a){
    float y = 1.0;
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
        y *= x;
    }
    return y;
}

float pot_sgn(int n){
    return (n%2 == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
}

float fact(int n){
    float f = 1.0;
    while(n>1){
        f *= n;
        n -= 1;
    }
    
    return f;
}

float abs(float x){
    return (x < 0.0) ? -x : x;
}
```

Why does it going on and how do I fix it (I mean making it give errors not more than `10^(-6)` for all test examples in `main()`)?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you include what the wrong answers actually are? You say what the answer *must* be, but not what they *currently* are.

Comment: @WilliamFleetwood , compile the code and you'll see

Comment: No, it is common practice to include all information in the question itself.